# How Do I Use HTML and CSS to Make this Specific Navigation Menu at the Top of a Website?

Tags: html, css

I am learning how to use HTML and CSS. I want to make a navigation menu at the top of the page. I attached a reference of what I want it to look like. I have the red background picture, but I was wondering how do I center the href link text over each picture.[Here is what I want the menu to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg7By.png)
This is the code I have started writing.

```
    <ul class="navigation-bar">

                <li>
                    <div class="tabs">
                        <img src=". . ." alt="home"/>
                        <a class="link" href="#">Home</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="tabs">
                        <img src=". . ." alt="support"/>
                        <a class="link" href="#">Support</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="tabs">
                        <img src=". . ." alt="contact"/>
                        <a class="link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: You could set the images as background images on your links. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image. To position the nav at the top you can use `position: absolute;` or `position: sticky;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is by adding a background image to the div via CSS and removing the img tag from the div.

```
 <div class="tabs" id="div1"> <! -- id to identify the div -->
        <a class="link" href="#">Home</a> <! -- make sure to add text align center -->
 </div>
```

```
#div1{
   background-image: url("your image here");
}
```